# Overriding method of standard control in SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, sapui5

Is there a way to override a method of a standard control in SAPUI5? I want to override the method **'_getAppointmentsSorted'** of [CalendarRow.js](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.ui.unified/src/sap/ui/unified/CalendarRow.js#1635)

I tried copy pasting the entire file and changing the method, but then I get the following error:

> failed to load
>   'be/amistaAdminPlanning/controls/MyCalendarRowRenderer.js' from
>   ./controls/MyCalendarRowRenderer.js: 404 - Not Found

I tried to fix this error by specifying the renderer like this:

```
    renderer: function(oRm, oControl) {
        sap.ui.unified.CalendarRowRenderer.render(oRm, oControl); 
    }
```

The CalendarRowRenderer is found, but the render method doesn't execute like it should and following error message pops up:

> ***Cannot read property 'getId' of undefined*** in *CalendarRowRenderer.js?eval:6*

Anyone any idea why it behaves like this?

### EXTENSION

```
sap.ui.unified.CalendarRow.extend("be.amistaAdminPlanning.controls.MyCalendarRow", {
    renderer: function(oRm, oControl) {
        sap.ui.unified.CalendarRowRenderer.render(oRm, oControl);
    }
});

function _getAppointmentsSorted() {

    var aAppointments = this.getAppointments();

    aAppointments.sort(function(oApp1, oApp2) {

        var iResult = oApp1.getStartDate() - oApp2.getStartDate();

        if (iResult == 0) {
            iResult = oApp2.getEndDate() - oApp1.getEndDate();
        }

        return iResult;

    });

    return aAppointments;

}
```

Comment: You should implement a custom control which extends the CalendarRow. Within your custom control you can override the method: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/d12d2ee6a5454d799358d425f9e7c4db

Comment: Custom component is the way to go. Don't try to override existing components' behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of "copy pasting the entire file" you should create your own custom control for example CalendarRowExtended and override the function in the custom control.

These links may be useful:

[Extending TextField Rendering](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/bcee26a4801748f39bf5698d83d903aa)

[Extending Buttons with Additional Events](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/d5b756bf4e9a4d67961fa21e1ba12c9e)

*Edit: Sorry, didn't see the comment from [Christoph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/395135/christoph) as it was written a few minutes before me. But I guess the idea was the same.*

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it in details but I think that following should work:

Create a file *app_name_space*/control/CalendarRowCustom.js
Folder 'control' is on the same level like 'controller', 'view' folders.

Fill CalendarRowCustom.js with following content:

```
sap.ui.define(
  ['sap/ui/unified/CalendarRow'],

  function(CalendarRow) {
    "use strict";
    return CalendarRow.extend("app_name_space.control.CalendarRowCustom",{
      _getAppointmentsSorted: function() {
        // Here goes your custom code
    },
    renderer: {}
  });
 }
);
```

According to [this example](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/d5b756bf4e9a4d67961fa21e1ba12c9e) in Documentation, `renderer: {}` should inherit the functionality from the parent control.

Then you should be able to use your custom control in a view like this:

```
<mvc:View controllerName="..." xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
   xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns:cust="app_name_space.control">

    <cust:CalendarRowCustom />

</mvc:View>
```

Substitute "*app_name_space*" with your defined namespace in the View as well as in the Control.

Comment: Thanks for your input, Sachad! But the method doesn't get called. Any ideas to why not?

Comment: This cannot work in this case because function _getAppointmentsSorted is not part of the prototype of the JavaScript object I think. You should use sachads approach, creating your own custom control and use  renderer: {} in your metadata.